# How to declare variables in jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to fetch the repo details from a variable in the jenkinsfile. Can someone guide on why this is not working?

```
                        parameters {
                        string(defaultValue: "develop", description: 'enter the branch name to use', name: 'branch')
                        string(defaultValue: "repo1", description: 'enter the repo name to use', name: 'reponame')
                    }

             stage('Branch Update'){
                       dir("${param.reponame}"){
                            bat """ echo branch is ${params.branch}"""
                       }
                   }
```

When i run the above, I get the following error message:

groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: param for class: groovy.lang.Binding
[Pipeline] }

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo. Instead of `param.reponame` it should be `params.reponame`.